# Store output from Unix command in C code

Tags: c, unix

```
int main()  {
    char buf[100];
    FILE *fp = popen("df -P /myLoc", "r");
    while (fgets(buf, 100, fp) != NULL) {
        printf( "%s", buf);
    }
    pclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Filesystem             512-blocks  Used  Available Capacity Mounted on
/dev0/vol0             123456      3456   5464675     4%    /sys
```

I got the output of command in buf variable. But I need to get the value of Capacity (4 in this case) into an integer variable. I think cut or awk command can be used but not sure how to make it work exactly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does `df -P | awk '{print $5}'` work for you?

Comment: May be `fstatfs` or `statfs` is better option than running the `df` command.

Comment: df -P | awk '{print $5}' --this gives the column name along with the value. I just need the value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use shell tools, you should write a shell-script.

If this really has to be in C you should use the system calls provided by POSIX instead of cobbling things together through `popen`. In you case that would be `statvfs` and the member `f_favail` of the `statvfs` struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/statvfs.h>

int main()
{
  struct statvfs buf;
  statvfs("/my/path", &buf);
  printf("Free: %lu", buf.f_favail);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you be able to please give an example as to how to use statvfs in a C code?

Comment: I am not getting the capacity value (4 in the question example). I am getting some value in the output though but not sure what it reflects.

Comment: @user32262 If I can bother you to read the documentation: http://linux.die.net/man/2/statvfs You will need to calculate the percentage yourself from the total inodes and the available ones.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your `df` command with `df -P /myLoc | awk '{print $5}' | tail -n 1 | cut -d'%' -f 1`.

This will return 4 in your case. Then you can use `atoi()` to convert it to an int.

But as others have suggested using system calls should at least be more portable.

Comment: I am getting this error - 
sed: Function s/\%//gi cannot be parsed.

Comment: Try using `cut`, I'll update my answer to reflect that. Just out of curiosity what OS is that?

Comment: The `sed` example I gave you was tested on Linux, didn't realise that it was not universal. The GNU utils really do spoil :)
EDIT: This works on HPUX, just tested it - `sed 's/\%//' `, adding `gi` is just a convention which was unnecessary here.